# Call Javascript Click event of HTML Control from C# Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, ajax

I am working in asp.net c#. I have a master page that has HTML anchor tag that changes the culture of website, when clicked.

```
<a id="LinkLanguage" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)"><asp:Literal ID="langltrl" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:skin, Français %>" /></a>
```

To handle the click event, I am doing the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $("#LinkLanguage").click(function (e) {     
        e.preventDefault();     
            $.ajax({        
            type: "POST",       
            url: "Default.aspx/LinkLanguage_Click",     
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',      
            dataType:'json',        
            success: function () { location.reload(); },        
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {       
                alert(xhr.status);      
                alert(xhr.responseText);        
                alert(thrownError);     
            }       
        });     
    });     

</script>
```

and the web method (Default.aspx/LinkLanguage_Click) that is being called to change the culture language is working in the following way:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["application.language"] != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["application.language"].ToString() == "en-CA")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["application.language"] = "fr-CA";
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["application.language"] = "en-CA";
            }
        }
}
```

Now, my question is on one of the content pages, I want to change the language based on the conditions. How can I call the language change anchor tag's(LinkLanguage) click event?

Following code is in content page:

```
if (Request.QueryString["Language"] == "FR")
{
   // Want to change language here
}
```

If I just assign session here i.e,

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["application.language"] = "fr-CA";
```

It needs a refresh, if I do response.redirect() to reload the page, it gives error page redirected too many time.

How can I make it work, Please help. Thanks

Comment: You cannot call JavaScript directly from the server side. All you could do is write some JavaScript to the page that executes on load.

Comment: Do you postback on change?

Comment: @dman2306 Can I write javascript on server side c# code behind?

Comment: @doutriforce, do you mean after language change? I am calling location.reload() on success.

Comment: `success: function () { location.reload(); }` This is an anti-pattern. If you want to re-load the page immediately following an ajax call, what's the point of the ajax call? Just do everything via a postback. Then you only have 1 request to the server, instead of 2.

Comment: "Can I write javascript on server side c# code behind". Sort of. You can inject script into the HTML that is rendered back to the browser, such that it executes as soon as the page is loaded into the browser.

Comment: I know it is @ADyson, but culture change requires a postback and I have an html control. If you can suggest me any other of doing it, it would be great.

Comment: use a button instead of a HTML control? You can make it look like a hyperlink (or anything else) using CSS.

Comment: The issue is I cannot use server control as this control is out of form server tag scope in Masterpage. I need to use HTML control.

Comment: In ASP.NET WebForms your form tag should cover everything in the page. There's no reason to have anything outside the tag. In fact if you're putting "runat=server" on a control outside the form tag then that's meaningless markup.

Comment: @Learner, If you really need to cause this postback, you could use ScriptManager to inject javascript on the page before loading it.